# Add Social Media icon widget to customizer

Tags: widgets, sidebar, theme-customizer

How can I add a Customizer widget to add social media icons with links to their social media profiles? To clear it up, I have created a few images with the inspect element.

**I want to have a section like this, with an *add widget* button:**

[image]

**When you click on it, the user will see the Social Media widget:**

[image]

**The user clicks on it and gets the following form:**

[image]

---

What have I tried? I have tried the examples on the [widgets API page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) and I have tried `register_sidebar`:

```
function arphabet_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Social Media button',
        'id'            => 'smb',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Link button',
        'id'            => 'lb',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    ) );

    class My_Widget extends WP_Widget {

        public function __construct() {
            $widget_ops = array( 
                'classname' => 'my_widget',
                'description' => 'Adds a new Social Media button',
            );
            parent::__construct( 'my_widget', 'Social Media button', $widget_ops );
        }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ) . $args['after_title'];
        }
        echo __( esc_attr( 'Hello, World!' ), 'text_domain' );
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
        $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
        ?>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( esc_attr( 'Title:' ) ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
        </p>
        <?php 
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

        return $instance;
    }
    }

    register_widget( 'My_Widget' );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );
```

But that didn't add a "Add Widget" button to the Widget section of the customizer. I'm not sure how I should work this out.

Comment: You also need to code last three functions `widget`, `form` and `update`

Comment: @Sumit Done that, edited the question, but the button is not really showing up yet

Comment: Great! Now note that `add widget` button is rendered automatically by WordPress when there are widget and sidebars available. First check, do you see your widget in `Appearance > Widget` ? And share the screenshot of customizer that what do you see ?

Comment: @Sumit http://i.imgur.com/FZIFLRY.png

Comment: Got it! See the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your widget is okay but problem is customizer do not show sidebar option if there is no sidebar is called on current viewing page.

You did register the two siderbars but did not call them any where in the template of page your are seeing in customizer.

Use [`dynamic_sidebar`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) function and call your sidebar somewhere in the template.

Example:-

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'smb' ); //For social media buttons sidebar
/* OR/AND */
dynamic_sidebar( 'lb' ); //For link button sidebar
```

Comment: Aaaah! You always have great answers, Sumit, thanks!

Comment: Your code works, but do you know how I can add the link button widget? Tried adding `class My_Widget extends WP_Widget {` and the contents with different names but that gave me an error..

Comment: Thank you @J.Doe What kind of error ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can make a plugin for this

```
<?php
/*
  Plugin Name: Adlivetech Social Profile Widget
  Plugin URI: http://adlivetech.com
  Description: Links to Author social media profile
  Author: Rohit Kaushik
  Author URI: http://adlivetech.com
 */

/**
 * Adds Adlivetech_Social_profile widget.
 */
class Adlivetech_Social_profile extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Register widget with WordPress.
     */
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
                'Adlivetech_Social_profile',
                __('Social Networks Profiles', 'translation_domain'), // Name
                array('description' => __('Links to Author social media profile', 'translation_domain'),)
        );
    }

    /**
     * Front-end display of widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::widget()
     *
     * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
     * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
     */
    public function widget($args, $instance) {

        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
        $facebook = $instance['facebook'];
        $twitter = $instance['twitter'];
        $google = $instance['google'];
        $linkedin = $instance['linkedin'];
        $instagram = $instance['instagram'];

        // social profile link
        $facebook_profile = '<a target="_blank" class="facebook" href="' . $facebook . '"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>';
        $twitter_profile = '<a target="_blank" class="twitter" href="' . $twitter . '"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>';
        $google_profile = '<a target="_blank" class="google" href="' . $google . '"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>';
        $linkedin_profile = '<a target="_blank" class="linkedin" href="' . $linkedin . '"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>';
        $instagram_profile = '<a target="_blank" class="instagram" href="' . $instagram . '"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>';

        echo $args['before_widget'];

        if (!empty($title)) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
        }

        echo '<div class="social-icons">';
        echo (!empty($facebook) ) ? $facebook_profile : null;
        echo (!empty($twitter) ) ? $twitter_profile : null;
        echo (!empty($google) ) ? $google_profile : null;
        echo (!empty($linkedin) ) ? $linkedin_profile : null;
        echo (!empty($instagram) ) ? $instagram_profile : null;
        echo '</div>';

        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    /**
     * Back-end widget form.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::form()
     *
     * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
     */
    public function form($instance) {
        isset($instance['title']) ? $title = $instance['title'] : null;
        empty($instance['title']) ? $title = 'My Social Profile' : null;

        isset($instance['facebook']) ? $facebook = $instance['facebook'] : null;
        isset($instance['twitter']) ? $twitter = $instance['twitter'] : null;
        isset($instance['google']) ? $google = $instance['google'] : null;
        isset($instance['linkedin']) ? $linkedin = $instance['linkedin'] : null;
        isset($instance['instagram']) ? $instagram = $instance['instagram'] : null;
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:'); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>">
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('facebook'); ?>"><?php _e('Facebook:'); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('facebook'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('facebook'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($facebook); ?>">
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('twitter'); ?>"><?php _e('Twitter:'); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('twitter'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('twitter'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($twitter); ?>">
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('google'); ?>"><?php _e('Google+:'); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('google'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('google'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($google); ?>">
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('linkedin'); ?>"><?php _e('Linkedin:'); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('linkedin'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('linkedin'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($linkedin); ?>">
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('instagram'); ?>"><?php _e('Instagram:'); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('instagram'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('instagram'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($instagram); ?>">
        </p>

        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::update()
     *
     * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
     * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
     *
     * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
     */
    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = (!empty($new_instance['title']) ) ? strip_tags($new_instance['title']) : '';
        $instance['facebook'] = (!empty($new_instance['facebook']) ) ? strip_tags($new_instance['facebook']) : '';
        $instance['twitter'] = (!empty($new_instance['twitter']) ) ? strip_tags($new_instance['twitter']) : '';
        $instance['google'] = (!empty($new_instance['google']) ) ? strip_tags($new_instance['google']) : '';
        $instance['linkedin'] = (!empty($new_instance['linkedin']) ) ? strip_tags($new_instance['linkedin']) : '';
        $instance['instagram'] = (!empty($new_instance['instagram']) ) ? strip_tags($new_instance['instagram']) : '';

        return $instance;
    }

}

// register Adlivetech_Social_profile widget
function register_Adlivetech_Social_profile() {
    register_widget('Adlivetech_Social_profile');
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'register_Adlivetech_Social_profile');

// enqueue css stylesheet
function Adlivetech_Social_profile_widget_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style('social-profile-widget', plugins_url('designmodo-social-profile-widget.css', __FILE__));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Adlivetech_Social_profile_widget_css');
```